# ROS logs with robot upstart

Tags: ros, roslaunch, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using robot_upstart to launch a single launch file when my system boots. I just noticed that when using robot_upstart the normal roslaunch log files do not appear under ~/.ros/log. I then run the kill all command and do roslaunch and the logs show up like normal. Does anyone know how I can enable logging with robot_upstart? Or if tthe logs are being stored elsewhere.

PARTIALLY SOLVED: I was getting an error trying to write the logs. I just never saw the error because, you know...  there where no logs. [Here is a related question](http://answers.ros.org/question/220780/problem-with-log-and-home-directories-and-roslaunch-handlers/) but it has no verified answer at this time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241886/ros-logs-with-robot-upstart/) by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 545 on 2016-08-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like robot_upstart saves its own log file under /var/log/upstart/[job-name].log. This log file looks like it has all node messages for every run, as opposed to the normal roslaunch logs which create a separate file for each node each time roslaunch is called. I wish there was a better log file to look at but at least its something.

---

Originally posted by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) with karma: 545 on 2016-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1